# Sluggish performance in web app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, performance, codeigniter

I am working on a web application based in CodeIgniter, with an interface that allows you to manipulate database records via ajax. Each database record that is presented to the user has several interactive buttons that are handled by jquery listeners. When there are, say, 800 records being displayed to the user, the app performs snappy. When there are 6000+, the app slows down to a crawl. Trying to interact with one of the records has a 10+ second lag time where the page basically freezes up.

I am loading all records on page load instead of incrementally to allow for instant searching/filtering of the list and to speed up some other functions. The HTML on the page adds up to 1mb when 6000 records are included. Is there an easy fix for the performance, or is loading so much html into the browser and watching it with jquery just not a good idea?

An example of my main listener for clicks on a record:

```
$(document).on('click', '.c:not(.ha, .sr, #u .c)', function() {
    var id = $(this).closest('.c').attr("data-id");
    getRecord(id);
});
```

Comment: I have a similar approach with more then 1 million records and I use https://www.datatables.net. The loading, filtering and ordering is done via ajax, it works very well.

Comment: How do you register event jquery listeners for those buttons? Can you show an example?

Comment: @Vaviloff , I have included an example of my listeners for those buttons.